# Calculating Colour Contrast for ASP

Tags: php, asp-classic, colors

I found this code snippet for PHP and Javascript, but I was wondering if it could be made work in classic asp? Here's a whole article on the topic for reference.

http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/

**PHP code**

```
function getContrast50($hexcolor){
    return (hexdec($hexcolor) > 0xffffff/2) ? 'black':'white';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nothing built into the language. Converting hex to decimal is as easy as `CLng("&H" & hexValue)` but from quick look in the PHP manual I saw that `hexdec()` method ignores any invalid characters, while the VBScript `CLng()` will just crash.

So here is a working function that as far as I can tell doing the same thing:

```vbs
Function GetContrast50(hexColor)
    Const strValidChars = "1234567890abcdef"
    Dim maxValue, decValue, sanitizedColor
    Dim x, curChar
    sanitizedColor = ""
    For x=1 To Len(hexColor)
        curChar = LCase(Mid(hexColor, x, 1))
        If InStr(strValidChars, curChar)>0 Then
            sanitizedColor = sanitizedColor & curChar
        End If
    Next
    If Len(sanitizedColor)=0 Then
        GetContrast50 = "invalid color string"
        Exit Function
    End If
    maxValue = CLng("&H" & "ffffff") 
    decValue = CLng("&H" & sanitizedColor)
    If decValue > (maxValue / 2) Then
        GetContrast50 = "black"
    Else  
        GetContrast50 = "white"
    End If
End Function
```

It's pretty easy to extend the validation to check the given string is in valid range.

Comment: I noticed an issue with the calculations it was doing. Using a value like #FFE6E6(a light pink colour) I end up returning white, which is too light to have white text on. I'm not sure if there might be something at issue with the calculations.

Comment: @jamEs oh my, sorry about that! Due to n00bish bug in my code "#FFE6E6" was actually seen as just "66" since the upper case letters were considered illegal characters. Fixed it now, see my edit.

Comment: I wanted to add that I made this tweak to the maxValue "If decValue > (maxValue / 1.3) Then" so it would flip to a white value a little earlier than it was doing. I found on some values the black text was a little too close in value to the background it was on, so that tweak made it function a little better.